# Event Listener / .getElementById Issue with Brave Browser

Tags: javascript

I started using Brave today and noticed some of my web apps / websites are not working.  Specifically, some buttons are not getting handled.  So, to troubleshoot, I added an IIFE with a window click handler to log this.id.  Brave console says `undefined` however the html button element clearly has the id attribute defined?  Am I missing something, or is Brave not fully baked yet?

```js
(function() {
  console.log('IIFE Fired.');
  window.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
  
  function clickHandler() {
      console.log(this.id);
  }
}());
```

```html
<head>
  <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,100,300,700italic,500,500italic,400italic,300italic,100italic|Roboto+Condensed:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.grey-deep_orange.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" id="credential-save">
    Save
  </button>

  <script src="//code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
(function() {
  console.log('IIFE Fired.');
  window.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);

  function clickHandler() {
      console.log(this.id);
  }
}());
```

Comment: Figured out my issue.  It had nothing to do with the Brave Browser.  I had copied/pasted in a tester `div` and forgot to change the `id` properties of a couple of buttons.  That effectively ruined my event listeners for the proper buttons.  So, ...my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely expected. In an event listener, `this` is the current event target. That is, it's the node to which you added the event listener. In this case, it's `window`. And it doesn't have an `id`.

```js
window.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log(this === window); // true
});
```

```html
<button>Save</button>
```

You should either not delegate the event and add the event listener to the button, or use the event target.

```js
window.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.id);
});
```

```html
<button id="credential-save">Save</button>
```

Comment: Yea, I saw this test returned same result across browsers?...  So, what the best way to attach an event listener to the whole page then handle based on `this.id`?  I \'ve done this before but can't find the old code to copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned event listener to window. I think, when it would be assigned to button, its id will be log. This your html.

```
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" id="credential-save">
Save
</button>
```

And this js

```
(function() {
  console.log('IIFE Fired.');
  var button = document.querySelector('button');
  button.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);

  function clickHandler() {
    console.log(this.id);
  }
}());
```

Comment: Right. That's how I had it.  But, I was thinking the reason my listener was failing was due to CSS `display:none` on the `div` on page load, i.e., I was hoping to not have to attach the listener as I brind `div`'s into view.  Thus, the overall window handler.  Sort of like jQuery's .on